# Android SQLite - How to represent groups within a table?

Tags: android, mysql, sql, database, sqlite

Let me start by giving a context.

I have 2 tables joined together by a many to many relationship as shown below.
[image]

In my Android application I have a need to show a list of the contents in the "JoinTable" (The join table will be filtered depending on the Table1 ID, this is the content that will be displayed to the user.)

Problem: I want the user to be able to group certain rows of the JoinTable together. I need to model this grouping system in the database so it can be queried later and the groups reappear. What is the best way to design the database with this capability?

*Some more detail from a user perspective:*
When a user selects an item from table one, that ID is sent to the next activity. The next activity queries the join table for the appropriate content. The way it's working now, it just shows one item per row from the JoinTable. The user should be able to for example, drag an item onto another item to group them together.

Comment: Do you want it to be possible for one JoinTable row to be part of several groups, or just 0/1?

Comment: You could use a [GROUP BY](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_group_by.htm) and use another table to populate the `GROUP BY` statements, i.e. with a `SELECT`

Comment: Based on what I understood, I would suggest you to add a “group” column to your SQLiteDatabase, which will store what group an element of the database belongs to.

Comment: @SnildDolkow No, that is not necessary. Basically when a user selects an item from table one, that ID is sent to the next activity. The next activity queries the join table for the appropriate content. The way it's working now, it just shows one item per row from the JoinTable. The user should be able to for example, drag an item onto another item to group them together. How would that be modeled inside a database?

Comment: Sounds like you only need a "group" column on your JoinTable, then (like @Swap said). Make sure to think about a good index on that table, to ensure performance in filtering/ordering.

Comment: @SnildDolkow I have considered that, and it seems like that may be the best course of action. I have also looked into using "GROUP BY" clauses, but i'm having a hard time understanding how they work. From my research, it looks like group by is to be used only with aggregate functions? How would I query the join table to be able to generate models from it with grouping?

Comment: Just make sure to order it by the "group" column -- then handle the displaying of the groups by letting your UI code detect when the group changes compared to the previous result.